# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, valgrind, root-framework

the first error in the  Valgrind:

```
 /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/var/root_data/global_product_id/global_product_id_cut.root
 ==14840== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
 ==14840==    at 0x8B264E0: inflateReset2 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
 ==14840==    by 0x8B265D8: inflateInit2_ (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
 ==14840==    by 0x5627ABA: R__unzip (in /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c /workspace/000-back-office/src/root/lib/libCore.so)
 ==14840==    by 0x5E1B409: TKey::ReadObjWithBuffer(char*) (in /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/src/root/lib/libRIO.so)
 ==14840==    by 0x5DFB673: TFile::GetStreamerInfoList() (in /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/src/root/lib/libRIO.so)
 ==14840==    by 0x5DF9CC9: TFile::ReadStreamerInfo() (in /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/src/root/lib/libRIO.so)
 ==14840==    by 0x5DFCE68: TFile::Init(bool) (in /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/src/root/lib/libRIO.so)
 ==14840==    by 0x5DFDE12: TFile::TFile(char const*, char const*, char const*, int) (in /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/src/root/lib/libRIO.so)
 ==14840==    by 0x43BBA6: ROOTproduct_id_record::loadROOT(bool) (ROOTproductidrecord.cpp:1078)
 ==14840==    by 0x42E5CD: ROOTproduct_id::loadROOT() (ROOTproductid.cpp:142)
 ==14840==    by 0x469D17: main (report_engine.cpp:528)
```

ROOTproductidrecord.cpp:1077-1078

```
std::cout<<filename_char<<"\n";
TFile* my_rootfile_pointer = new TFile(filename_char); //open an existing file for reading (default).
```

as you can see the filename_char has  a value...  the next functions (TFile::TFile) are from a stable  CERN library.

I can't understand what is wrong in the ROOTproductidrecord.cpp:1078   ...

Comment: Is `filename_char` initialized?

Comment: `as you can see the filename_char has a value` well...

Comment: "as you can see the filename_char has a value." Where can we see that?

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=577135 - probably a bug in zlib. Try updating your packages.

Comment: I have to agree with a few people here before. There is nothing in your code example that shows that filename_char is initilized. Just try to add filename_char = 'a'; before "new TFile(.." and see if the error goes away.

Comment: The code
     std::cout<<filename_char<<"\n";

create the output    
       /media/d2bfa67b-a3e7-4dde-9f3a-119260e3a29c/workspace/000-back-office/var/root_data/global_product_id/global_product_id_cut.root

Comment: @Mat I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS  . The Ubuntu Software center has  installed the zlib1g 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4,   zlib1g:i386 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4  ...

Comment: Bump this bug then: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zlib/+bug/1071315 - there's nothing Stack Overflow can do for you here. The bug's not in your code. We can't fix your distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq36 :
"Valgrind (or some similar memory access checker) says that deflate is performing a conditional jump that depends on an uninitialized value. Isn't that a bug?

No. That is intentional for performance reasons, and the output of deflate is not affected. This only started showing up recently since zlib 1.2.x uses malloc() by default for allocations, whereas earlier versions used calloc(), which zeros out the allocated memory. Even though the code was correct, versions 1.2.4 and later was changed to not stimulate these checkers."